# Canvas element with offset

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Draws nothing if the item is biased.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9UyxF/

JavaScript:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("drawing").getContext("2d");

$("#drawing").mousemove(function(e) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx.stroke();
});

var ctx_without_offset = document.getElementById("without_offset").getContext("2d");

$("#without_offset").mousemove(function(e) {
    ctx_without_offset.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    ctx_without_offset.stroke();
});
```

CSS:

```
#drawing {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
}
#without_offset {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"If the item is biased"*... What? Does the canvas prefer trackpads over mouse input?
Silliness aside: what exactly is the problem? What do you expect to happen, and what is happening?

Comment: You need the position **relative** to the canvas, not to the window.

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you want to happen and what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The coordinates on the canvas, and cooridnates of `clientX` and `clientY` have different origins. This version realigns them:

```
function makeDrawFunction(elem) {
    var context = elem.getContext('2d');
    return function(e) {
        var offset = $(elem).offset();
        context.lineTo(e.clientX - offset.left, e.clientY - offset.top);
        context.stroke();
    }
}


$("#drawing").mousemove(makeDrawFunction(
  document.getElementById("drawing")
));

$("#without_offset").mousemove(makeDrawFunction(
  document.getElementById("without_offset")
));
```

[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sabof/99uva/)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem comes from how you get the mouse position.

`clientX` and `clientY` returns the mouse position relative to the page.

I don't know if there is something with jQuery to get the right coordinates, but you can try this :

```
.lineTo(e.clientX - this.offsetLeft, e.clientY - this.offsetTop);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to "normalize" pointer coords like:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("drawing").getContext("2d"),
    ctx_rect= ctx.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

$("#drawing").mousemove(function(e) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - ctx_rect.left, e.clientY - ctx_rect.top);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

In that case you'll have pointer coords relative to the canvas. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BuDpz/.
Also note that calculating offsets on every mousemove may affect the performance. That's why it's better to calculate it once, save values and update them on demand later.

Answer (score 1):

Use pageX and pageY that will handle scroll offset for you, then subtract the offset position of the canvas and that's it.
Try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/9UyxF/14/

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("drawing").getContext("2d");

$("#drawing").mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    ctx.lineTo(e.pageX - pos.left, e.pageY - pos.top);
    ctx.stroke();
});

var ctx_without_offset = document.getElementById("without_offset").getContext("2d");

$("#without_offset").mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = $(this).offset();
    ctx_without_offset.lineTo(e.pageX - pos.left, e.pageY - pos.top);
    ctx_with
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for the offset of the element, too. You can find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9UyxF/6/). As I'm in a rush it's quick and dirty, but it works.

```
$("#without_offset").mousemove(function(e) {
    var left = e.clientX - $("#without_offset").offset().left;
    var top = e.clientY - $("#without_offset").offset().top;
    ctx_without_offset.lineTo(left, top);
    ctx_without_offset.stroke();
});
```